# Client and Server Using the Same Machine

Tags: java, networking

I am making my game act the same in multiplayer and singlplayer. Do do this, I have to host a server on the users' computer when they play singleplayer. How does one make a server on local host with Java? Is it as simple as:

```
echoSocket = new Socket(localhost, 1234);
```

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~amyles/tutorials/tcpchat/) out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is:

```
java.net.ServerSocket serverSocket = new java.net.ServerSocket(port);

while(true){
    java.net.Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    // do something
    // If you want to handle multiple connections at a time,
    // you will have to create a Thread for each socket.
}
```

**Edit:** If you want your server only to listen on localhost (so no other computer can connect) you would write:

```
java.net.ServerSocket serverSocket = new java.net.ServerSocket(port);
serverSocket.bind(new java.net.InetSocketAddress("localhost", port));
```

Comment: I would just add some sort of manual check to make sure some other computer isn't connecting; correct?